# How to make a unittest by using fluent validation and Xunit?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I am planning to use Fluent validation in Unittest via Xunit. I am using Fluent. Validation Library for validation rule. But it is throwing the below error.But I am trying to create "ValidationException" How can I throw "ValidationException" error?

```js
Xunit.Sdk.ThrowsException: 'Assert.Throws() Failure
Expected: typeof(System.AggregateException)
Actual:   (No exception was thrown)'
```

CODE:

```js
        [Fact]
        [Trait("Category", "Unit")]
        public void Should_MyOrder_Throw_ValidationException_Successfully()
        {
            // Arrange
            var orderId = "123";
            

            var fixture = new Fixture();
    
            fixture.Customize<Order>(composer =>
                composer.With(_ => _.OrderNo, orderId)
                        .With(_ => _.DeliveryNo, 0)
                        .With(_ => _.Name, "XXXXXX"));



            var order = fixture.Create<Order>();
            var orderEvent = new OrderEvent(
                CloudEventFactory.CreateNew(OrderEvents.OrderUpsert, orderId, order));

            _mock.Setup(x => x.Validate(order)).Throws(new ValidationException("ValidationException"));

            _orderRepositoryMock
                .Setup(_ => _.FindByOrderIdAsync(orderId, OrderEvents.EventType, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(null as OrderEvent);

            // Act
            void act() => _sut.ProcessOrderAsync(orderEvent, new CancellationToken()).Wait();
            // Assert
            var caughtException = Assert.Throws<AggregateException>(act);
            Assert.Equal(typeof(ValidationException), caughtException.InnerException.GetType());
        }
```

Comment: You're expecting a `ValidationException`, but explicitly specify that an `AggregateException` is thrown. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As a step to debugging/analysis: what happens if you modify ``act()`` to directly throw your exception ``void act() => throw new ValidationException("Bla");``. If your assertion works, then the problem is in your mock; if the assertion fails, then the problem is in the formulation of the assertion.